# Add Instance to env in awsfabric

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto, fabric

From this Python fabric program, I should print the details of EC2 instance.

```
@task
def ec2_print_instance(full=False):
    """
    Print EC2 instance info.

    :param full: Print all attributes, or just the most useful ones? Defaults
        to ``False``.
    """
    instancewrapper = Ec2InstanceWrapper.get_from_host_string()
    print 'Instance:', instancewrapper['id']
    print_ec2_instance(instancewrapper.instance, full=full)
```

Above method calls the below class EC2InstanceWrapper.

```
class Ec2InstanceWrapper(object): 
    def __init__(self, instance):
       self.instance = instance
    def __getitem__(self, key):
       return getattr(self.instance, key)
    def __str__(self):
       return 'Ec2InstanceWrapper:{0}'.format(self)
    def add_instance_to_env(self):
       if not 'ec2instances' in env:
            env['ec2instances'] = {}
        env['ec2instances'][self.get_ssh_uri()] = self
        if not env.key_filename:
            env.key_filename = []
        key_filename = self.get_ssh_key_filename()
        if not key_filename in env.key_filename:
            env.key_filename.append(key_filename)
    @classmethod
    def get_from_host_string(cls):
        """
        If an instance has been registered in ``fabric.api.env`` using
        :meth:`add_instance_to_env`, this method can be used to get
        the instance identified by ``fabric.api.env.host_string``.
        """
        return env.ec2instances[env.host_string]
```

If I run this program, getting AttributeError: ec2instances.
I need to add my host to env by using the add_instance_to_env method. How to do this?